# Cannot connect to Postgres running on VM from host machine using MD5 method

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, vagrant

I have a VM set up with Vagrant that has Postgres running on it (on port 5432), forwarded to port 8280 on the host machine.

I have set the password for the default user and I can connect locally just fine.

I have been trying to set up access from the host machine over port 8280, and I have been unable to get it working with 'MD5' as the trust method.

I have set up `postgresql.conf` to listen on all addresses:

```
# postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*'
```

and I have configured `pg_hab.conf` as follows:

```
# pg_hab.conf
#TYPE   DATABASE  USER  CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD
host    all       all   0.0.0.0/0     md5
```

With all of these settings, if I run the following command from my host machine:

```
psql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8280 --username=postgres -d mydb -c '\l'
```

I am prompted for the password, and then I get:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

If I then change the METHOD from 'md5' to 'trust' I'm not asked for a password and I can connect as expected. My question is - why can't I connect using 'md5', which is what I want to be able to do? I know that the password I am entering is correct (I have changed it), but for some reason it isn't working.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same exact problem. The issue was on the host side, basically the firewall was blocking the port I was using. So this is what I did (I am using OSX Mavericks)

1. Open the port (Host)

   `sudo ipfw add 7000 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 7001`
2. Modify Vagrantfile in order to allow portforwarding

   `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 7001`
3. Edit postgresql.conf (Guest)

   `listen_addresses = '*'`
4. Edit `pg_hba.conf` (you might want to tune this better)

   `host    all       all   0.0.0.0/0     md5`
5. Now, from the host connect normally using the port (in my case 7001) and 'localhost' as host address

Comment: Thanks! What need to be tuned in pg_hab.conf?

Comment: Well, "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" will allow connections from any host, that's why I said you might want to change it to something more restrictive.

Comment: To allow only the Vagrant host you can use `host all all 10.0.2.2/32 trust` - replace `trust` by the method you prefer

Comment: For those landing from Google; I also I found my port forward hadn't taken effect through `vagrant provision` so had to do `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a password for the `postgres` user. It does not have one by default, so you cannot connect.

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'somepassword';
```

Your local connections probably work because they're using unix sockets with `peer` authentication, not TCP/IP. If you use:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres postgres
```

on the VM, you'll probably find that that fails too, because you're actually testing TCP/IP based connections now.

Comment: Thanks Craig, but you may not have seen in my last paragraph - I have already set the password, and I can connect to the database using it so I know it's correct.

Comment: @HugoRodger-Brown ... in which case I'd be checking to see if I was really connecting to the DB I thought I was. Try enabling detailed logging in the guest and looking for auth errors in the logs, or using tcpdump in the guest and tracking the traffic.